# Запись строки в файл

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, qt5, запись

Есть программа в Qt5. Хочу записать переменные типа `QString` в текстовый файл таким образом: `%s %s %s`.

Есть ли аналог `fprintf` в `QFile`?

Пробовал сделать через стандартный файловый поток `FILE *f`, там и `fprintf` и т.д, но файл не открывается. Ошибки  в коде нет, но сам файл не открывается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: QString предоставляет много способов для форматирования строки, а вариантов как записать эту строку в файл немеренно и все это описано в хелпах. Уточните конкретно, что Вы хотите сделать, желательно привести кусок кода с указанием того места, в котором возникла проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Уже сделал сам, `QTextStream out(&file); out<<name<<" "<<lastname<<" "<<phonenumber<<"\n"; QMessageBox::information(this, "Успешно", "Данные записаны");` хотел аналог fprintf для QString, чтобы в файл записать 3 строки через пробел

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант:

```
QTextStream out(&file);

out << QString("%1 %2 %3\n").arg(name).arg(lastname).arg(phonenumber);
```

Или с другим [arg](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-15):

```
out << QString("%1 %2 %3\n").arg(name, lastname, phonenumber);
```